# 'Unauthorized' error when requesting '/joinedTeams' from Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am setting up an app for modifying a Microsoft Teams account (teams/channels) through the Microsoft Graph API, but I can't get responses from all of the endpoints which I need to call.
I have followed the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for creating an app with application permissions and acquired access (and refresh) token(s) succesfully.

Calling the  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user guid>/joinedTeams` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) yields a response as follows:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-24T12:37:53",
      "request-id": <guid>
    }
  }
}
```

while calling endpoints such as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` works [as described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). It would seem that the app hasn't gotten consent and/or permissions to access these, but after signup they are listed on the API permissions in the azure portal enterprise applications page, and the access token JWT contains the specified permissions as a `roles` object.

From the JWT:

```
"roles": [
    "TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "TeamMember.ReadWrite.All",
    "Team.ReadBasic.All",
    "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All",
    "Member.Read.Hidden"
  ]
```

I have tried with the `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission and also with the full permission list listed on the [permissions page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) for the `/joinedTeams` endpoint and they all elicit the same error.

Curiously, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors) a *401 - Unauthorized* response would be given for expired (or similarly invalid) tokens, however that seems to clearly not be the case as I can call other endpoints with that very token.

What am I missing?

Comment: kind of weird, besides the token validation, they decided to add an additional validation. **Additionally this error may occur, if you try to use a delegated access token granted to a personal Microsoft account, to access an API that only supports work or school accounts (organizational accounts).**, if that's not the case, would suggest to open an issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Along with the @abestrad's point, can you also check if you have granted "Admin consent" for the permissions if required.

Comment: @abestrad Yes i saw that note, but I have set it up with application permissions.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Admin consent has been granted both from the app registration side and from the "installing" enterprise application side.

Comment: did you update your requested scopes?

Comment: @Homungus what do you mean? The scopes are defined on app registration by the application and permissions for those are requested (and cornfirmed) in the user Oauth flow.

Comment: @Krukke that's what i meant - often adjusting the requested scopes is forgotten after changing api-permissions in ad.

Comment: @Krukke, Can you try decoding the bearer token [here](https://jwt.io/)  and share the "scp" object

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT as it has application permissions, there is no scp. I have added the current contents of the "roles" field in the JWT to the OP.

Comment: @Krukke, The "roles" object looks fine. Can you please share the request id and timestamp of the issue.

Comment: Most recent unauthorized response:
`{"error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-29T06:32:46",
      "request-id": "88edfa84-df64-4f53-9f9f-f1b3db0fc23d"
    }}}`

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT forgot to tag you.

Comment: @Krukke - I experienced the same thing - but realized that I had created my app in the wrong AAD directory. Suggest going to your AAD and under Licenses, make sure you see 'Microsoft Teams" listed

Comment: @MikeOliver It is not listed there (only an "Enterprise Mobility + Security E5" trial is). But when i log in to Teams on the installing account, I have an organisation there. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: @Krukke, Do you have Teams Licence? Can you please confirm it.

Comment: @Krukke That was the same situation that I had. I believe you have two directories tied to your Azure Portal email. If you log into Azure portal, go to top right and drop down your identity, you'll see a Switch Directory choice. If you switch, you should see a directory that has Microsoft Teams license. That's the directory that you have to add your MS Teams app - then the tokens you get for it should be valid. I believe this is a quirk as to how free sign up for MS Teams works, it creates a new directory attached to your email vs. allowing you to choose an existing one

Comment: @MikeOliver there is indeed a Microsoft Teams license on another directory. I didn't realise that it had created another directory when i signed up to Teams. I will check tomorrow if that solves the issue.

Comment: @Krukke yep, makes sense - this is exactly what happened to me too.. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @MikeOliver
When I signed up for Teams it created another directory. Only that second directory had a Teams "license" (visible from the azure portal's License page).