# I am looking for the name of Teams's license which will be required to get token from teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

[This question is particularly in continuation of this answer. Can anyone throw some more light on this Team's integration with name of license and Active Directory settings ] ['Unauthorized' error when requesting '/joinedTeams' from Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555955/unauthorized-error-when-requesting-joinedteams-from-microsoft-graph)

Comment: What do you mean by "the name of Teams's license which will be required to get token from teams"? Please provide more details.

Comment: Let me describe my usecase here- I have a Teams account in my company's work account like we all have. I have to make an app which sends messages in that team's channel with my work account email. This app needs to be registered and an access token has to be authenticated with Team's API to send messages on channel. With organisation's Azure account, it is not allowing to authenticate with error message 'Unauthorized error' (given the thread above).  If I create a separate tenant in Azure and purchase Office 365 E5 license, will it be able to authenticate with my Organisation's teams channel?

Comment: You need to add the required permissions to send messages to channel using API. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) and add required permissions to send messages.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT thanks I did explore this approach as well. My use case is using a low-code platform. I am exploring around doing it with Logic apps as it gives integration with Teams and it should have access within my organisation's tenant also.

Comment: what do you mean for logic apps? Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT The link you shared is what actually I am doing- just the token that is obtained is valid only for an hour- I am looking to make it a more persistent one.

Comment: Using logic apps to send messages to teams channel with a 'trigger-action' approach. It does work but not solving the purpose.

Comment: You need to add permissions for you app in the azure to send messages to channel using the graph API. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are just referring to the Teams product license that you assign to users to give them permission to use Teams. The license is just called "Microsoft Teams" and can be applied at the user or group level in the Microsoft 365 admin center, or in bulk via Powershell.

You can [assign the license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/user-access) by either the Licenses page or the Active Users page.

By default, when a licensing plan (for example, Microsoft 365 Enterprise E3 or Microsoft 365 Business Premium) is assigned to a user, a Teams license is automatically assigned, and the user is enabled for Teams. You can disable or enable Teams for a user by removing or assigning a license at any time.

[image]

You can also add [add-on licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-add-on-licensing/microsoft-teams-add-on-licensing?tabs=small-business) for specific features.